# InfoPath 2013 - Filtering Data Connection using dates

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections

My current form filters the secondary data connection using an empID. Then I use formatting rule to hide non-overlapping period. Which works well but since our data is growing, I'm wondering if there's another way I can improve performance by using a second filter using dates?

Current Form Rule: when control (empID) is changed,

- Set field value: empID (Secondary/Query) = empID (Main)
- Run Query

Formatting rules for the repeating table (Secondary), hide row if

- End Date (Main) < Start Date (Secondary) **OR**
- End Date (Secondary) < Start Date (Main) **OR**
- ID (Secondary) = ID (Main)

I only want to retrieve any data that overlaps with current request.

Example Secondary Data Source:

- Employee1   08/01/2017  08/01/2017
- Employee2   08/01/2017  08/01/2017
- Employee1   08/14/2017  08/28/2017

If current request is Employee1 08/15/2017-09/01/2017, I only want to return the 3rd item from Secondary data source. Rather than retrieving **all** data associated with Employee1